# ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor() does not call ContentProvider.openFIle

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, storage-access-framework

I implemented a `ContentProvider` by overriding `openFile(...)` method. Then I tested it by using `ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(...)` method. As specified in the javadoc, `openFileDescriptor` suppose to call `ContentProvider.openFile`:

"...Open a raw file descriptor to access data under a URI. This is like `openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri, String)`, but uses the underlying `openFile(Uri, String)` `ContentProvider.openFile()` method..."

The problem is the `openFile()` method was never called. Instead I observed that `openAssetFile()` was called instead. I tested it with android 4.1.2r1. When I review the source code for the android class ContentResolver (4.1.2) I see that `openFileDescriptor()` will just call `openAssetFileDescriptor()`, and I cannot find any execution path where `ContentProvider.openFile()` would be called at all.

Anybody has any idea where I was wrong? - Thanks

Here is my test method call:

```
context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(bitmapUri, "r").getFileDescriptor();
```

My `bitmapUri` is something like this "content://com.myprovider.authority/filename"

Comment: see whats done in openAssetFileDescriptor(), it explains everything

Comment: I actually looked at openAssetFileDescriptor() as well. In some cases an AssetFileDescriptor will be created directly (such as when the Uri scheme is "File" I belive). In other cases openTypedAssetFileDescriptor will be called. In any case, I cannot find any path that results in ContentProvider.openFile beeing called. If you know it can you elaborate?

Comment: look for SCHEME_CONTENT

Comment: Have the exact same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

That seems like a bug in openFileDescriptor() to me. I ended up calling `ContentResolver.openInputStream()/ContentResolver.openOutputStream()`. These methods correclty call `openFile()` to get to the file.

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
ContentProviderClient providerClient = resolver.acquireContentProviderClient(uri);
ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = providerClient.openFile(uri, "r");
```

Dont forget to release ContentProviderClient.

Comment: The documentation is very misleading, making it look like a bug. 

What happens is that calling `ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()` first tries `ContentProvider.openAssetFile()`. If `openAssetFile()` fails, then it falls back to `openFile()`. What this means is that if your ContentProvider has implemented `openAssetFile()`, then `openFile()` will never get called. So you can either do some pass-through where `openAssetFile()` calls `openFile()` manually, or just don't implment `openAssetFile()`. The trick with ContentProviderClient also works.